# How to set accessibility text for Google Map marker in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, accessibility

I am trying to set the content description for Android Google Map marker. But I am not able to set content description for marker. It reads the markerOptions.title and markerOptions.snippet. But I want to read the content description.

For example, if user enabled the accessibility I want to read my content description instead of this title and snipet. If it is a view I can able to set the content description. But Marker is not a view. And also not able to get that marker by accessibility delegate also. I tried like following:

```
public static void setAccessibilityOnFocus(Class class_name, String accessibilityLabel, Context ctContext) {

        if (ClientAppProperties.isAccessibilitySupport()) {
            AccessibilityManager manager = (AccessibilityManager) ctContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
            if (manager.isEnabled()) {
                AccessibilityEvent e = AccessibilityEvent.obtain();
                e.setEventType(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT);
                e.setClassName(class_name.getName());
                e.setPackageName(ctContext.getPackageName());
                e.getText().add(accessibilityLabel);
                manager.sendAccessibilityEvent(e);
            }
        }

    }
```

And calling this method by

```
setAccessibilityOnFocus(marker.getClass(), accessibilityLabel[position], mContext);
```

But this is read the label on first load time. If there is 100 marker it is reading the 100 marker at a time. I want to read when user select a marker. What can I try next?

Comment: Have you tried using [AdvancedMarkers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/advanced-markers/overview) for Android? If you check the documentation, one of its feature is actually to let you set any Android View as the marker, and I'm thinking this might work with your use case.